# How to create a schedule widget in MVC asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a widget for a class schedule which is present on my page. This page is rendered from the ActionResult method present in my controller.

I have zero knowledge on how to do this. Please help. Thanks in advance. Please see the screenshot attached for reference.

```
public ActionResult SchedulingWidget()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/SchedulingWidget.ascx");
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate?.

Comment: I have added screenshot for reference and better understanding please check. Thanks

Comment: you want to make the class schedule as widget correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. And I want to use this widget on the customer's website. @arvind

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Widget
    {
        public string Action { get; private set; }
        public string Controller { get; private set; }
        public object RouteValues { get; private set; }

        public Widget(string action, string controller, object routeValues)
        {
            Action = action;
            Controller = controller;
            RouteValues = RouteValues;
        }
    }


@model Widget.Controllers.MasterIndexModel

@foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets)
{
    try
    {
        Html.RenderAction(widget.Action, widget.Controller, widget.RouteValues);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Widget.Controllers.Logger.Log(widget, ex);
    }
```

> you can use a wrapper kind of wrap your controller and action init and
>   use it as a child  as a widget

for more info look at [Steve Fenton's article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-mvc-widgets-renderaction/)
 he also explains about performance wise also.